# I have two wicket feedback panel in the same page and both respond to the same error message

Tags: java, wicket, feedbackpanel

I have two differend Wicket FeedbackPanel in the same page, one is for error messages and the other for success messages. The problem is when i call feedback1.error("bla bla bla") both the feedback panels were painted.

```
feedbackErrorOptionsPanel = new FeedbackErrorPanel("feedbackErrorOptionsPanel");
feedbackErrorOptionsPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
feedbackErrorOptionsPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
feedbackErrorOptionsPanel.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
feedbackErrorOptionsPanel.setFilter(new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(this));
add(feedbackErrorOptionsPanel);

...

feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel = new FeedbackSuccessPanel("feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel");
feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel.setEscapeModelStrings(false);
feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel.setFilter(new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(this));
add(feedbackSuccessOptionsPanel);

...

feedbackErrorOptionsPanel.errorWithLink("messaggio da visualizzare", "Per aggiungere clicca qui!", WebPage.class, null);
```

the method errorWithLink is used to add a link insisde the message error. This metod call the error() method inside my class that extend FeedbackPanel

Can anybody tell me how can I call feedback1.error to display with the first and feedback2.success to display with the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FeedbackPanel has constructor that accepts IFeedbackMessageFilter - `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel#FeedbackPanel(java.lang.String, org.apache.wicket.feedback.IFeedbackMessageFilter)`.

You can pass `org.apache.wicket.feedback.ExactLevelFeedbackMessageFilter` with the respective level to both of them.

Answer (score 1):

you should use ErrorLevelFeedbackMessageFilter (or ExactLevelFeedbackMessageFilter) instead of ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter to obtain the desired behavior. for more details check the [user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_displaying_feedback_messages_and_filtering_them).